# Time formatting using logging module in python

Tags: python

I am planning to use logging module to monitor elapsed time for each script execution(event).
I used this code:

```
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Start:')
time.sleep(5)
logging.info('Complete:')

print("Hello World!")
```

In example.log I have this:

```
01/14/2015 09:16:15 PM Start:
01/14/2015 09:16:20 PM Complete:
```

My goal: I want to calculate elapsed time i.e. between Complete and Start and I can't easily subtract  09:16:20 PM - 09:16:15 PM.

My question: how could I reformat datefmt in basicConfig in order to get time in seconds. I want to do simple operation by subtracting two values and monitoring when it's too long.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling `basicConfig` with this format instead:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', format='%(created)f %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

This should generate the following log entries (your times will differ obviously):

```
1421288969.379916 Start:
1421288974.385206 Complete:
```

I'm inferring from your question that you're going to parse the log file afterwards to compute durations.  `%(created)f` produces the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch as floating point values, so hopefully this will facilitate your computation.

Comment: All answers are good but I like more yours because it's simple. Thanks

Comment: Well I realized that times did not differ in a few cases. I need time not in seconds but in milliseconds. What you suggested works but returns time in seconds. How could I change format (created) f to return in milliseconds. Thanks. Note: in my case events often lasts less that second and I fail to get diff

Comment: Please never mind since I found that I could use %(msecs)d and it returns me time in milliseconds

Comment: I am afraid that %(msecs)d will not serve my problem. Since I care only about time delta between two events using only msecs might give wrong result. I think that I need to compare two epoch time in msecs.  Could someone help me with format operator to get time in logging expressed in msecs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[*Delorean*](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean) can help you with the parsing and conversion to regular *timedate* objects, so you can determine the delta.

The following code takes the format you have in your logs and can calculate the delta:

```
from delorean import Delorean
from delorean import parse

st = parse("01/14/2015 09:16:15 PM")
end = parse("01/14/2015 09:16:20 PM")

diff = end.naive() - st.naive()

print diff
```

The output is:

> 0:00:05

`st` and `end` are both `Delorean` objects with timezone *UTC*, e.g.

```
>>> print st
Delorean(datetime=2015-01-14 21:16:15+00:00, timezone=UTC)
```

`diff` is a `datetime.timedelta` object, e.g.

```
>>> diff = end.naive() - st.naive()
>>> type(diff)
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you leave `basicConfig` as is, for readability, and later, when you read the logs, extract the date and time by `datetime` parsing.  E.g:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datefmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'  # the same you used for logging
>>> logline = '01/14/2015 09:16:15 PM Start:'  # as read from the log
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join(x.split()[:3]), datefmt)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 21, 16, 15)
>>> _.timestamp()
1421298975.0
```

These are your seconds-since-the-epoch, so getting the difference in seconds between the time stamps of successive lines in the log is easy.  (The `.timestamp()` part requires Python 3.3 or better, but in earlier version you can take the difference between the `datetime` objects and call the `total_seconds` method on that time-difference object).

Comment: Folks, I realized that I need not seconds diff ( I have it now when use epoch time ) but rather milliseconds since some of the events lasts less then a sec. Could someone advice how to handle basicConfig and milliseconds? Thanks

Comment: If your operating system returns times precisely, `total_seconds` returns a float, so the milliseconds are there, you just need to tweak the `datefmt` for logging purposes (to _show_ those milliseconds).

Comment: - Alex, thanks for comment. I realized that in my case when I use format='%(created)f % (message)'s I've got result in epoch like this: 1422280320.156000 Start:event3
1422280320.234000 Complete:event3
1422280860.138000 Start:event1
1422280860.138000 Complete:event1
where value after the dot is likely milliseconds. In case like event1 it lasted less than msec but in case like event3 I could get time delta. I assume that is what I expected ... thought not sure why time delta is zero